# How to select WPF TreeViewItem which has been populated using XmlDataProvider?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, xmldataprovider

I have a WPF `TreeView` which has been populated from an XML file at runtime. I click on a button and a `FileDialog` box appears and then I select an XML file. Then the XML file is loaded in the `TreeView`. I have used a `XmlDataProvider` and some `HierarchicalDataTemplate`s to load the XML.

I have added an action handler with the TreeView, but when I select an item of that TreeView I can't find any reference of that item. I only find the reference of the first element.

How can I solve this issue?

The XAML is:

```
<Window x:Class="Demo2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="MEIInformation" XPath="/MEI" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Case" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></TextBlock>            
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Phase" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Trigger" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"></TextBlock>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>  
<Grid>
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar>                
            <Button ToolTip="Open Test Suite" Click="OpenTestSuite">
                <Image Source="Icons/open.png"></Image>
            </Button>                
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
    <TreeView x:Name="trv" FontSize="14" Height="518" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,31,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431">
        <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MEIInformation}, XPath=*}" Header="Suites"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>                           
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code snippest is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{     
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();     
        this.trv.MouseRightButtonUp+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(DoSomething);      
    }    

    private void OpenTestSuite(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            xmlDocument.Load(open.FileName);
            XmlDataProvider dataProvider = this.FindResource("MEIInformation") as XmlDataProvider;
            dataProvider.Document = xmlDocument;         
        }
    }        

    private void DoSomething(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Do Something in TreeView!");
        TreeViewItem childItem = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        if (childItem != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(childItem.Header.ToString()); // or MessageBox.Show(childItem.toString);
            childItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No Selected Item!");                    
    }                
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MEI>
    <Case Name="Jean Price">
        <Phase Name="January">
            <Trigger Name="Order # JAN001"></Trigger>
            <Trigger Name="Order # JAN002"></Trigger>
        </Phase>
        <Phase Name="February">
            <Trigger Name="Order # FEB001"></Trigger>
        </Phase>
    </Case>
    <Case Name="John P Grant">
        <Phase Name="April">
            <Trigger Name="Order # APR001"></Trigger>
    <!-- ... -->
</MEI>
```

I just want to have a reference of that item so that i can add new item after that item.

---

@Mart
I have changed the treeview on the xaml like this... (added SelectedItemChanged="DoSomething")...

```
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="DoSomething"....../>
```

And the c# code is now.......

```
private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Do Something in TreeView!");           

            TreeViewItem childItem = sender as TreeViewItem;                        
            if (childItem != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(childItem.Header.ToString());
                childItem.IsSelected = true;
                MessageBox.Show("It Works!");
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("No Selected Item!");                    
        }
```

but there is no luck at all. And i have not understood ur UIElement sugestion...:(

Comment: Can you please paste your code snippet here so that we can find out what exactly went wrong

Comment: the xml is:  The xml file is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<MEI>
  <Case Name="Jean Price">
    <Phase Name="January">
  <Trigger Name="Order # JAN001">
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Name="Order # JAN002">
  </Trigger>
    </Phase>
    <Phase Name="February">
  <Trigger Name="Order # FEB001">
  </Trigger>
    </Phase>
  </Case>
  <Case Name="John P Grant">
    <Phase Name="April">
  <Trigger Name="Order # APR001">
  </Trigger>
  <Trigger Name="Order # APR002">
  </Trigger>
    </Phase>   
 <Phase Name="May">
  <Trigger Name="Order # MAY001">
  </Trigger>
 </Phase>
  </Case>
</MEI>

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I found to get the `selectedTreeViewItem` value, I got it from `xmlElement`.

Considering this xaml code:

```
<i>
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Filial"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="/WpfClient;component/Images/image4.png"
                   Height="20"></Image>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"
                       FontSize="18"
                       FontFamily="BankGothic Md BT"
                       Foreground="#FF355CE5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Setor"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"
                       FontWeight="Bold" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="User">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding XPath=@source}"
                   Height="15"></Image>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                       Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"
                       FontStyle="Italic" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlDP"
                     Source="Contatos.xml"
                     XPath="/Contatos/Filial"></XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Width="Auto"
      Height="Auto">
    <TreeView Name="tv"
              ItemsSource="{Binding }"
              DataContext="{StaticResource xmlDP}"
              Margin="0,0,0,0"
              TreeViewItem.Selected="tv_Selected">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded"
                        Value="True" />
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</i> </pre>
```

and this c# codebehind:

```
private void tv_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlElement xmlElement= (XmlElement)tv.SelectedItem;

        string mySelectedValue = xmlElement.Attributes[0].Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(mySelectedValue , "SelectedTreeValue", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    </i>
```

and this is the xml file:

```
<i>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Contatos>
    <Filial name="Firm">
      <Setor name="Sector 1">
        <User name="user1" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/user.png"></User>
        <User name="user2" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/user.png"></User>
        <User name="user3" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/admin.png"></User>
      </Setor>
     <Setor name="Sector40">
        <User name="user43" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/admin.png"></User>
        <User name="user44" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/user.png"></User>
        <User name="user45" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/user.png"></User>
        <User name="user46" source="/WpfClient;component/Images/user.png"></User>
     </Setor>
   </Filial>
</Contatos>
</i>
```

Comment: For Future Reference: Just be aware that the TreeViewItem.Selected does not show via intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see what fires you `DoSomething` handler, I guess it responds to a `Click` event.

If it is a Click on an element of the item template, you may not get the correct sender parameter.

You can cast the sender to an `UIElement` and then access its `DataContext` which should be one of your XML element.

The other way is to react to the treeview's `SelectionChanged` event, that will give you the treview item in the event arguments.

Comment: Actually   this.trv.MouseRightButtonUp+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(DoSomething);   fires the DoSomething Method....

Comment: Doing like this will not give you the treeview item as a context but the treeview. You can access your item if it is selected (a right click doesn't necessarily select the item) with trv.SelectedItem.

Comment: In your SelectionChanged event handler, put a breakpoint and observe the type of the sender object and e.Source. These object depend on how you placed your handlers. Then cast them correctly and follow my suggestion above.

Comment: So your question is rather "How to display a context menu on my treeview items?". You should add a true ContextMenu into your HierarchicalDataTemplate like explained here: http://www.wpftutorial.net/ContextMenu.html

Comment: If you want to ass subitems in your treeview, the recommended way is to benefit from the databinding: add elements to your XML and they should reflect in the treeview. Otherwise, take a look at the ItemContainerGenerator and its ItemFromContainer and ContainerFromItem methods.